# How to add a reset button that clears my code?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a basic TicTacToe UI in python, and I believe that a fundamental item to this code is a reset button which resets your codes back to the default. is there any other way to do this?

I've Tried to define a function which resets the text of the button back to " " but I don't think that's a great idea because of a lot of other complexities within the cod.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def changetext():
  BTN1["text"] = "X"
BTN1 = Button(root, text=" ", command=changetext)
BTN1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

So I want to add a button here that says "Reset Text" and it resets all the codes to defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to reset the game would be to

- Reset the UI as you suggest, with a single dedicated `reset_UI()` function
- Reset the board state by creating a new game board object, and discarding the old one

This of course means that you'll need to wrap all your variables and functions in a board class `Board`, so that there aren't a billion global variables you have to worry about resetting. The only thing that should persist between resets are your UI buttons, which can be created in your `main()` function before initializing the game board.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code demonstrating how something like that could be done (plus a few other things):

```
import tkinter as tk


def toggle(btn):
    if btn["text"] == "X":
        btn["text"] = " "
    else:
        btn["text"] = "X"

def reset(buttons):
    for btn in buttons.values():
        btn["text"] = " "

root = tk.Tk()

buttons = {}
for row in range(3):
    for col in range(3):
        button = tk.Button(root, text=" ", width=1, height=1)
        button.config(command=lambda btn=button: toggle(btn))
        button.grid(row=row, column=col)
        buttons[row, col] = button

reset_button = tk.Button(root, text="Reset", command=lambda: reset(buttons))
reset_button.grid(columnspan=3)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Great example, Thank you!